# How do I save my Selenium Side-Runner results to a file?

Tags: selenium, selenium-ide

I'm starting to learn the Selenium IDE.  I want to run my tests using the command line (selenium-side-runner).  I want to output the results in a file using the JUnit format.  When I run a simple command though, I get an error that the output folder already exists.  Here's my command:

```
selenium-side-runner --output-directory=results --output-format=junit .\OutputTests.side
```

And the error:

```
Error: EEXIST: file already exists, mkdir 'C:\path\results'
  at Object.mkdirSync (fs.js:753:3)
  at sync (C:\Users\jrobinson\Desktop\side-suite-httpslearn.microsoft.comen-us\node_modules\mkdirp\index.js:71:13)
  at sync (C:\Users\jrobinson\Desktop\side-suite-httpslearn.microsoft.comen-us\node_modules\mkdirp\index.js:77:24)
  at sync (C:\Users\jrobinson\Desktop\side-suite-httpslearn.microsoft.comen-us\node_modules\mkdirp\index.js:78:17)
  at sync (C:\Users\jrobinson\Desktop\side-suite-httpslearn.microsoft.comen-us\node_modules\mkdirp\index.js:78:17)
  at sync (C:\Users\jrobinson\Desktop\side-suite-httpslearn.microsoft.comen-us\node_modules\mkdirp\index.js:78:17)
  at sync (C:\Users\jrobinson\Desktop\side-suite-httpslearn.microsoft.comen-us\node_modules\mkdirp\index.js:78:17)
  at sync (C:\Users\jrobinson\Desktop\side-suite-httpslearn.microsoft.comen-us\node_modules\mkdirp\index.js:78:17)
  at sync (C:\Users\jrobinson\Desktop\side-suite-httpslearn.microsoft.comen-us\node_modules\mkdirp\index.js:78:17)
  at sync (C:\Users\jrobinson\Desktop\side-suite-httpslearn.microsoft.comen-us\node_modules\mkdirp\index.js:78:17)
```

The command creates the "results" folder, but leaves it empty.  During the run, the command creates another folder called `side-suite-httpslearn.microsoft.comen-us`, and then deletes it.  That folder has some files in it, but it is deleted before I can see them.

My test suite has one test in it that succeeds.  I'm using Chrome.  What am I doing wrong?  My command is nearly the same as [what's in the documentation](https://selenium.dev/selenium-ide/docs/en/introduction/command-line-runner#output-test-results-to-a-file).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem was that I had entered the base URL as my project's name.  That's not a valid file name.  When I changed the project name to "pname" it worked.